# 5.5.52-MariaDB vs 5.6.15 mysql Trigger not work

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I have a Problem, local I installed 5.6.15 mysql and this trigger does its job properly:

```
BEGIN

  IF New.id_category_default = 566
    THEN
      SELECT COUNT(*) DATA INTO @conta
          FROM `lorcustomization_field`
          WHERE `id_product` = Old.id_product ;

    IF @conta <=0
      THEN
        INSERT INTO `lorcustomization_field`(`id_product`,`type`,`required`)
            VALUES(Old.id_product,1,0);

    SELECT `id_customization_field` DATA INTO @idfield FROM `lorcustomization_field`
    GROUP BY `id_customization_field` DESC LIMIT 1;


    INSERT INTO `lorcustomization_field_lang` (
      `id_customization_field`,
      `id_lang`,
      `id_shop`,
      `name`
    )
    VALUES
    (
      @idfield ,
      1,
      1,
      'prova'
    );

    END IF;
  END IF;
END
```

I remotely have 5.5.52-MariaDB and the trigger stops at the first input when it meets the other selector stops.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the involved tables as well as some example data and indicate the time (`BEFORE | AFTER`) and event (`INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE`) of the trigger?

Comment: Sorry   AFTER  UPDATE table lorproduct

Answer (score 0):

** Change

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) DATA INTO @conta
      FROM `lorcustomization_field`
      WHERE `id_product` = Old.id_product ;

IF @conta <=0
  THEN
```

to

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
      FROM `lorcustomization_field`
      WHERE `id_product` = Old.id_product )
  THEN
```

** Change

```
   GROUP BY `id_customization_field` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

to

```
   ORDER BY `id_customization_field` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

** If you don't already have these, add

```
INDEX(id_product)
INDEX(id_customization_field)
```